# distributed rendering best option

Tags: rendering, blender

Please suggest some good options for distributed rendering
i know a few of them like loki render and drqueue, lux renderer
if some one already using any of the above or something else please suggest which is the best option

Answer (score 0):

If you're not worried about 'leaking' proprietary info try using the community
http://www.renderfarm.fi/